# Parsing command output from bash

Tags: bash, scripting

I am not very adept at bash so please forgive my ignorance.

I am writing a script where I need to parse the output of a command invocation which may result in several elements.

If I issue this command at the prompt:

```
res=$(/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -LDInfo -Lall -a0 | grep "RAID Level" | awk '{print $4}' | tr -d ',')
```

and echo the response I get:

```
Primary-1 Primary-5 Primary-5
```

which is what I want. 
However when I attempt this in a script:

```
AID=0
MCLI=/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64
function test {
        RAIDGS=$($MCLI -LDInfo -Lall -a$AID | grep 'RAID Level' | awk '{ print $4 }'| tr -d ',' )
        echo "got RAIDGS = $RAIDGS"

}
```

It does not appear to be set, I get:

```
got RAIDGS =
```

What am I doing wrong?

Your help is greatly appreciated.
Using:
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: The first command uses `-Lall`, and the second one does not.

Comment: Avoid naming your function as `test` since that is a shell bulletin.

Comment: You don't need the `grep` command: `awk '/RAID Level/ { print $4 }'`.

Comment: Anubhava, thanks that is just an illustrative name. The script much larger function is named getPhysicalGeometry I though I would simplify it.  Jordanm, thank you that is a typo introduced in the cut and paste. Sorry, however the actual command did have it and I have re-instated it in the original question. The problem persists.

Comment: echo the full command before execution from shell and from inside the script. Also compare env variables from shell and from script.

Comment: I was able to get what I wanted in a round about way. I captured the output of the command to a variable, echoed this and the parsing worked. A work of caution using this approach is that the resulting variable where the output was captured must be echoed within quotation marks to preserve the white space and let the filters do their thing. I still am at a loss as to why the original approach failed.